# USING R: Three-way Non-Parametric ANOVA Equivalent? Similar to Kruskal-Wallis But for 3?

Tags: r, anova, kruskal-wallis

I have a data set that needs each factor to be sorted by both Year and Type... so like

[image: Year 2020 2019 2020 2019 2018 2018]

I can perform Kruskal-Wallis for each factor by Year or by Type. But is there a way for me to evaluate each factor by both? Similar to the ANOVA?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you are seeing recommendations for statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. Once you know what test you want to perform and are unable to see how to do it in R on google, then feel free to post here with those details added.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the closest to what you're looking for is `mantelhaen.test`.
Although you better use `kruskal` with mann-whitney afterwards.